# Hardware capabilities of android wear devices

Tags: wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

First of all I don't know whether this the right place to ask this question or not

My sincere apologies if this is not the correct place for this question

Is Android wear watches are independent of connecting to WiFi and GPS or it is mandatory to pair up with the handset before connection?

What are the independent hardware capabilities of android wear devices with out pairing to handset?

Any technical articles links related to this helps me a lot

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

AndroidWear devices need to use a phone (via BLE) to access sensor and network data.  The AW are designed to be extensions of the Android Phone, and not really independent devices.  The watch will be very limited without a phone attached.

This is how the AW platform is designed to work.  The watch is a notification center, and a remote display for the phone.

https://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html

Comment: ya got it thanks. is it possible to get any links or articles which explains the design or communication between AW and phone.TIA

Answer (score 0):

Google Wear uses Google Services API to communicate, using Bluetooth (we cannot use Internet protocols directly on the watch as it's blocked by Google). So without pairing it, it's just a dumb watch.

Comment: Did you know links or articles which explains the design or communication between AW and phone.